# css center middle element in div for multiple screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="add_nav_header">
    <div class="centerButtons">
        <a class="btnLogout smallBtn" data-role="button"></a>
        <a class="btnSearch smallBtn" data-role="button"></a>
        <a class="btnViewList smallBtn" data-role="button"></a>
    </div>
</div>

.centerButtons {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.add_nav_header {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}
.smallBtn {
  float: right;
  margin: .3em;
  padding: .6em;
  font-size: .9em;
}
.btnLogout {
  float: right;
}
.btnViewList {
  float: left;
}
.btnSearch {
  left: -33%;
}
```

This is my html and css and I want to center the middle btnSearch button but I don't want to have to set the left percentage for every screen size with media queries.

[**jsfiddle** example](http://jsfiddle.net/m3m9m7L4/)

Comment: Try setting the width of .btnSearch to whatever the width is.  If that doesn't work, create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `text-align: center` to the container and remove `float` from div you want to be centered.

```
.centerButtons {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.add_nav_header {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}
.smallBtn {
    /* float: right; */
    margin: .3em;
    padding: .6em;
    font-size: .9em;
    display: inline-block;
}
.btnLogout {
    float: left;
}
.btnViewList {
    float: right;
}
/* .btnSearch {
  left: -33%;
} */
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zfh1ono0/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but this link might help you: [CSS centering](http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/). The key is this line:

> transform: translate(-50%, -50%);